# Points of continuity of Baire class 1 function on Cantor set?

Tags: baire-category, cantor-set

Consider the Cantor set $2^\omega$ of infinite binary strings, and we define metric/distance as $x, y \in 2^\omega,\; d(x, y) = 2^{-k}$ where $k$ is the longest common prefix of $x$ and $y$.

**Question 1.**
Consider some function $F(x) : 2^\omega \rightarrow R$.
If $F(x)$ satisfies both 1) and 2):

1) $F(x) = 0$ for any $x$ that ends in a cycle of $0$s (e.g. $x = \overline{0}$ or $x = 01101\overline{0}$)

2) $F(x) = 1$ for any $x$ that ends in a cycle of $1$s (e.g. $x = \overline{1}$ or $x = 01100\overline{1}$)

then, is $F(x)$ necessarily nowhere continuous on $2^\omega$?

I think the answer is yes: because for any $x \in 2^\omega$, and any neighborhood of radius $r$ (i.e. the set of strings that shares a common prefix of length $-\log_2 (r)$ with $x$), we can always find $x'$ and $x''$ in the neighborbood where $x'$ ends in $0$s and $x''$ ends in $1$s, and thus either $|F(x) - F(x')|$ or $|F(x) - F(x'')|$ *cannot* have an upperbound by $\epsilon$.

If the answer to Question 1 is false, then ignore Question 2.

**Question 2.**
Consider the function $f_p(x) : 2^\omega \rightarrow R$, parametrized by $p$ where $0 < p < 1$:
$f_p(x) = p \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^i x_i$
where $x_i$ is the $i$-th digit of $x$.

If we take the pointwise limit of $f_p(x)$, 
$$
\newcommand\defeq{\stackrel{\mbox{def}}{=}}
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} f_p(x) \;\defeq\; \hat{F}(x)
$$
I think that $\hat{F}$ satisfies both 1) and 2):

First notice that $\forall 0 < p < 1, 0 \le f_p(x) \le 1$.

a) For any $x$ that ends in a cycle of $0$s after an arbitrary prefix of length $L$:
$$
p \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^i \cdot x_i  = p \sum_{i=0}^{L} (1-p)^i \cdot x_i \le p \sum_{i=0}^{L} (1-p)^i = 1-(1-p)^{L+1} 
$$
$$
\implies 0 \le \hat{F}(x) \le \lim_{p\rightarrow 0} 1-(1-p)^{L+1} = 0 \implies \hat{F}(x) = 0
$$

b) For any $x$ that ends in a cycle of $1$s after an arbitrary prefix of length $L$:
$$
p \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^i \cdot x_i \ge p \sum_{i=L}^{\infty} (1-p)^i \cdot x_i = (1-p)^L
$$
$$
\implies 1 \ge \hat{F}(x) \ge \lim_{p\rightarrow 0} (1-p)^{L} = 1 \implies \hat{F}(x) = 1
$$

However, I think $f_p(x)$ is continuous on $x \in 2^\omega$, and therefore $\hat{F}(x)$ by definition is a Baire Class 1 function. According to [Wikipedia on Baire class 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1)

> By another theorem of Baire, for every Baire-1 function the points of continuity are a comeager Gδ set (Kechris 1995, Theorem (24.14)).

It seems that $\hat{F}$ cannot be nowhere continuous, which contradicts answer to Question 1 (if answer to Q1 is true, that is)?

Could someone help me figure out which step of my reasoning is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the puzzle with help from a colleague.

The problem was that there are some $x$ such that the limit
$
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} f_p(x)
$
does not exist (therefore $\hat{F}$ is not completely defined on $2^\omega$).

One example where the limit does not exist was 
$$x = \underbrace{0}_{u_1}\;\underbrace{11}_{u_2}\;\underbrace{000000}_{u_3}\;\underbrace{1...1}_{u_4}...$$
where $u_i = i!$.

Though I was not able to rigorously prove that this limit for this $x$ doesn't exist, I was able to plot $f_p(x)$ and pretty confident that it diverges.

It would be nice if someone can formally prove that the limit doesn't exist.

[plot of $f_p(x)$, horizontal axis is $\ln(p)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frrsj.png)